# Trying to write into TCP stream (to CSTA capable telephone server) but DataAvailable is always false

Tags: .net, tcp, telephony

I'm trying to send a CSTA-XML message to a telephone server. I'm supposed to send the message using TCP with a frame specified in "ECMA-323 Appendix J.2" (see also https://blog.jonaskoeritz.de/2016/10/23/understanding-csta-part-1/). No matter how I try to set up the message and the frame DataAvailable is always false and the response empty.

After I finished my studies I never had to work on a web application or do anything else that would require me using TCP, so my knowledge is extremely rusty. I'm not sure if the problem is in how I send the message or the XML message itself, so I'm first trying to find out if I'm doing something wrong sending the message. Since I get no response at all instead of an error message I assume it is the former.

The server is a Mitel MiVoice Office 400. CSTA is activated, the IP and Port are correct and the port is listening and the user I'm trying to log in with has a CSTA license. I've tried sending various XML strings to start a session,  but never get any reaction from the server. The XML string in the example is just one of many variations I have tried. Though considering I get no response at all I'm assuming the problem is at a more fundamental level and not an issue with the XML. I took the XML string right out of the manual for the telephone server and tried serveral variations of it.

```
Private Function TestConnection(msg As String, Optional addDataFrame As 
   Boolean = True) As Boolean         
        Dim PBX_Port As Int32 = 1234
        Dim PBX_IPAddress As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.111")

        Using TCP_Client As New TcpClient()
            Dim TCP_Encoder As New UTF8Encoding
            TCP_Client.Connect(PBX_IPAddress, PBX_Port)

            Using TCP_Stream As NetworkStream = TCP_Client.GetStream
                Dim bytes(TCP_Client.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
                Dim responseData As String = ""

                If TCP_Stream.CanRead = False Then MsgBox("Can't read")
                If TCP_Stream.CanWrite = False Then MsgBox("Can't write")

                Dim Header As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(0)
                ReDim Preserve Header(2)

                Dim InvokeID As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(CInt(1))
                ReDim Preserve InvokeID(4)

                Dim MessageBody As Byte() = TCP_Encoder.GetBytes(msg)

                Dim MessageLength As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(Header.Length + InvokeID.Length + MessageBody.Length + 2) '2 = size of MessageLength field
                ReDim Preserve MessageLength(2)

                Dim Data As Byte()
                If addDataFrame Then
                    Data = Combine(Header, MessageLength)
                    Data = Combine(Data, InvokeID)
                    Data = Combine(Data, MessageBody)
                Else
                    Data = TCP_Encoder.GetBytes(msg)
                End If

                TCP_Stream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length)
                TCP_Stream.Flush()
                'EDIT: Tried with and without flush and also tried adding Thread.Sleep(10000) here

                If TCP_Stream.DataAvailable Then MsgBox("Data available")
                TCP_Stream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(TCP_Client.ReceiveBufferSize))

                responseData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)

                If responseData = "" Then
                    Return False
                Else
                    For Each b As Byte In bytes
                        If b.ToString <> "0" Then Return True
                    Next
                    Return False
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
   end function

Private Function Combine(first As Byte(), second As Byte()) As Byte()
    Dim result(first.Length + second.Length - 1) As Byte
    Buffer.BlockCopy(first, 0, result, 0, first.Length)
    Buffer.BlockCopy(second, 0, result, first.Length, second.Length)
    Return result
End Function

    Dim msgStartApplication As String = <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
                                                 <applicationInfo>
                                                    <applicationID>CSTA_Test</applicationID>
                                                    <applicationSpecificInfo>
                                                        <SessionLoginInfo xmlns="http://www.aastra.com/csta">
                                                            <userName xmlns="">xxx</userName>
                                                            <password xmlns="">xxx</password>
                                                        </SessionLoginInfo>
                                                    </applicationSpecificInfo>
                                                </applicationInfo>
                                                   <requestedProtocolVersions> 
                                                    <protocolVersion>http://www.ecma-international.org/standards/ecma-323/csta/ed5"</protocolVersion>
                                                   </requestedProtocolVersions>]]>.Value
```

TCP_Stream.DataAvailable is always false. ResponseData is always empty or only contains zeroes if I try to read it anyway. I'm expecting at least something akin to an error message.

Comment: Things take time to process, you can't expect an instant response the moment after you sent your data. Also calling `.Read` without using the `int` it returns is 100% always a bug, you MUST use that return value to know how much data was actually sent to you.

Comment: I tried with Thread.Sleep (10000) as well just to be sure

Comment: It is how you use Read is the problem. Its too much to explain in a comment but google "NetworkStream Read tutorial" the main point is you have to call read repeatedly until you get the amount of data you expected.

Comment: That can't really be the problem though if DataAvailable returns false!? I looked at some examples using the search string you suggested. Some do it the same way I did in my OP, others loop while DataAvailable is true (which is false for me)